# Walking through the object that contains arrays

Tags: javascript, loops, object, for-loop

That's my javascript object.

```
var myobj = {
'arr1': ['abc','dsf2','ss4'],
'arr893f': ['839f','mdo9','ks92','kcm8'],
 ....
}
```

How to walk through all the values of arrays that are inside of this object?
I.e. I need to walk through `'abc','dsf2','ss4', '839f','mdo9','ks92', ...`

I can walk through

```
for (var value in myobj ) {
  console.log(value);//arr1, arr893f
}
```

but that's still not what I need.
I need to get `'abc','dsf2','ss4', '839f','mdo9','ks92', ...` into the console by walking through the object.

P.S. Only structure of this object is known. We don't know the key names or values.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for(var propName in myobj)
{
    if(myobj.hasOwnProperty(propName)){
        var item = myobj[propName];
        if(item instanceof Array)
        {
            item.forEach(function(arrItem, index){
                //woo!
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I thought it might be useful to create a convenience method on the `Object.prototype`:

```
(function(){
    function enumerateProperties(cbHandler, ownProperty){
        ownProperty = typeof(ownProperty) == "boolean" ? ownProperty : true;
        if(typeof(cbHandler) != "function"){
            throw new Error("invalid callback");
        }
        for(var propName in this){
            if((!ownProperty) || this.hasOwnProperty(propName)){
                cbHandler(propName, this[propName]);            
            }
        }
    }
    Object.prototype["enumerateProperties"] =
          Object.prototype["enumerateProperties"] || enumerateProperties;
})();
```

so now you can:

```
var o = {a:1, b:[1, 2, 3], c:3};

o.enumerateProperties(function(propName,propValue){
    console.log(propName);
    if(propValue instanceof Array){
        console.log(propValue.join(", "));
    }
    else{
        console.log(propValue);
    }
});
```

Comment: typeof called on an array will return 'object', try checking for a length maybe.

Comment: Did you missed a closing ")" ? Thank you.

Comment: Yes. Sorry @Haradzieniec.

Comment: @Haradzieniec : I added a little extra.